# How do I apply my custom UnmarshalJSON method to an embedded struct?

Tags: go

So, I have struct P. I need to unmarshal some json data into P but sometimes it comes embedded struct, Embedded. In either case, I unmarshal the json from the API and need to format the "Formatted" field. It seems in the Embedded case my unmarshaller doesn't get called.

I [have the following code](https://play.golang.org/p/7-GLx01-pl):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type P struct {
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    Formatted string `json:"formatted"`
}

type Embedded struct {
    A struct {
        B struct {
            *P
        } `json:"b"`
    } `json:"a"`
}

func (p *P) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    type Alias P

    a := &struct {
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(p),
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &a); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    a.Formatted = fmt.Sprintf("Hi, my name is %v", a.Name)

    return nil
}

func simple() {
    b := []byte(`{"name":"bob"}`)

    p := &P{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &p); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("normal: %+v\n", p)
}

func embedded() {
    b := []byte(`{"a":{"b":{"name":"bob"}}}`)

    e := &Embedded{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &e); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("embedded: %+v\n", e.A.B.P)
}

func main() {
    simple()

    embedded()

}
```

(I realize I can get rid of the custom unmarshaller and create a method to format the name but wanted to see if this way was possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough to explain all the reasons, I will just list what works and what doesn't. Someone more knowledgeable can fill you in on the reasons behind it.

The following works when B is a `*struct`, not sure why.

```
type Embedded struct {
    A struct {
        B *struct {
            P
        } `json:"b"`
    } `json:"a"`
}
```

The following also works. I'm guessing that using an anonymous struct had some effect in the last one since a `*struct` is not required here.

```
type embedP struct {
            P
}

type Embedded struct {
    A struct {
        B embedP `json:"b"`
    } `json:"a"`
}
```

The following works if `*P` is initialised.

```
type embedP struct {
            *P
}

type intermediate struct {
        B embedP `json:"b"`
}

type Embedded struct {
    A  intermediate `json:"a"`
}

e := &Embedded{A:intermediate{embedP{P:&P{}}}}
```

But the same thing doesn't work with anonymous structs.

```
type Embedded struct {
    A struct {
        B struct {
            *P
        } `json:"b"`
    } `json:"a"`
}

e := &Embedded{A : struct{B struct{*P}`json:"b"`}{B: struct{*P}{&P{}}}}
```

[Play link](https://play.golang.org/p/nS_HmVx3kD)

Other improvements

If `p := &P{}` is already a pointer you don't need to pass &p in json.Unmarshal. `json.Unmarshal(b, p)` would suffice. Same with `e := &Embedded{}`.

Answer (score 3):

To extent @John's answer, take a look at the source code of json decoder, especially method [`indirect(v reflect.Value, decodingNull bool)`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?s=3976:4024#L460) line 442-483.

> // indirect walks down v allocating pointers as needed,
>   // until it gets to a non-pointer.
>   // if it encounters an Unmarshaler, indirect stops and returns that.
>   // if decodingNull is true, indirect stops at the last pointer so it can be set to nil.

The method returns, `json.Unmarshaler`, `encoding.TextUnmarshaler` and the value of `v`. **In current implementation**, inside the method, basically the following *steps* were executed

1. If argument `v` is **not a pointer**, it will return immediately without checking whether `v` implements `json.Unmarshaler/encoding.TextUnmarshaler` or not. The method assigns `nil` for both unmarshaller regardless `B` implements custom unmarshaller or not.
2. If argument `v` **is a pointer**, it will check whether `v` implements `json.Unmarshaler/encoding.TextUnmarshaler` or not. In this case, if `v` is nil, a new value will be assigned to `v`.

If `Embedded` is defined as

```
type Embedded struct {
    A struct {
        B struct {
            *P
        } `json:"b"`
    } `json:"a"`
}
```

when, decoding `"b":{"name":"bob"}` to field `B`, since `B` is not a pointer, (1) is applicable. As the result, custom unmarshaller is returned as `nil`, thus never being called. The json decoder uses default unmarshaller to decode json value to `B`'s fields.

If `Embedded` is defined as

```
type Embedded struct {
    A struct {
        *B struct {
            P
        } `json:"b"`
    } `json:"a"`
}
```

since field `B` is a pointer, (2) is applicable. The decoder allocates new `struct{*P}` to `B`, detects that `B` implements custom unmarshaller, then call it as expected. The following declaration

```
type Embedded struct {
    A struct {
        *B struct {
            *P
        } `json:"b"`
    } `json:"a"`
}
```

also works, if `P` is preallocated, i.e.

```
//...
e := Embedded{}
e.A.B = &struct{ *P }{P: &P{}}
//...
```

If it's not preallocated, in (2) the decoder will assign `&struct{*P}{}` to `B`, then call the custom unmarshaller with `B.P == nil`. As the result, json value can't be captured by `B.P` during unmarshall.

**Note**:
I'm not sure whether it is desired behavior or not, and I can't find a clear documentation related to embedded struct.